# sum the values of column matching and not matching and write to a different files

Tags: shell-script

```
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.0      139264
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.1      15657
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.0      139264
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.1      156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.2      156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.3      156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.5      172236
```

OutPut File1 ( with matching servers)

```
Server1                 Vzise
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.0      278528
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.1      172236
```

OutPut File2 ( with out matching servers)

```
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.2      156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.3      156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.5      172236
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{Arr[$1]+=$2;Count[$1]++}END{for(i in Arr){if(Count[i]>1){print i,Arr[i] > "out_1"}else{print i,Arr[i] > "out_2"}}}' file1

$ ls -lrt
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 272 Nov 14 15:45 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 102 Nov 14 15:48 out_2
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy  68 Nov 14 15:48 out_1

$ cat out_1
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.0 278528
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.1 172236


$ cat out_2
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.2 156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.3 156579
DR_CNDAOFSZAPZP_GPFS_VOL.5 172236
```